# geolocation cordova can't get a latitude

Tags: cordova, geolocation

i'm using cordova geolocation, and i need to get a coordinates values outside of a function. Ex latitude value. But it doesn't works.

I've tried diferent ways but no one works .

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">



        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);


    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                                    'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />';


    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

                           }

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
    <script>alert (lat);</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added **"cordova-plugin-geolocation"** for getting geo location & in your code actually you need to put **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);**   inside a function and call it . like this

```
`function getLocation() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (onSuccess, onError);
}`
```

if u want to call it via button click then put  getLocation() in onclick handler and call it or onload any other.

Comment: I've already added, the problem is if i do alert(..) inside function, works, bur i need to get  a long value outside of function

Comment: @CarlosJulian U cannot call  **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError)** directly u have to place this in a function and call it it works then and if u check with the office documentation of cordova also it is like that only

Comment: But, can i get latitude value out of this funtion, like if i have to like to put it on a form field?

Comment: Yes you can get the data just check it once [link] https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html

Comment: Yes, but can i get a longitude value outside of a function??? Like  <input type="text" name="firstname" value= <script>long</script><br> .....

Comment: @CarlosJulian u want to display long and lat in a textbox ?